# HTML Video buffering very slowly when source is a GET request

Tags: html, flask, get, apache2

I'm working on a webapp that shows HTML videos to the user, the source of these videos is a get request to a flask server that will return the correct video if the user is authenticated correctly. The code is as follows:

HTML:

```
<video id="movie" width="100%" controls autoplay>
   <source src="/flask/server/video?title=xxxxxx.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Flask:

```
@app.route('/flask/server/video')
def return_video():
    if jwtVerify(request.cookies): # used for authenication
      filename = request.args.get('title')

      find_the_actually_video_file_location()   # not in the static or public_html dir

      file = realLocation + str(filename)
      
      return send_file(file)

    else:
      return redirect(url_for("login"))
```

Using this method means the real directory of the video file isn't exposed to the user, authentication must be completed and the video doesn't need to be in the public_html or static folder.

However, this results in significant buffering (especially when scrubbing) as opposed to using:

```
<video id="movie" width="100%" controls autoplay>
   <source src="/static/real/movie/dir/xxxxxx.mp4"type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Which I don't want to use as no authentication is required if someone can get the exact URL to the files and the files must be in the static or public_html directory.

How can I speed up the first method so it doesn't buffer or alternatively enable the second method to only be accessible to those authenticated?

Apache2 + Flask + Jinja on Ubuntu Server 20.04.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using Nginx you'd use [`X-accel`](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/).

> This allows you to handle authentication, logging or whatever else you
> please in your backend and then have NGINX handle serving the contents
> from redirected location to the end user, thus freeing up the backend
> to handle other requests. This feature is commonly known as
> X-Sendfile.

I would think there's an equivalent for Apache.

Your code would look something like the following:

```
@app.route('/flask/server/video')
def return_video():

    if not jwtVerify(request.cookies): # used for authenication
        return redirect(url_for("login"))
    
    # Autheticated OK
    
    # real file location
    _file = "/var/www/files/my-big-document.pdf"
    
    _size = os.path.getsize(file)

    # File URI - see Nginx docs
    _uri = "/protected_files/my-big-document.pdf"
    
    response = make_response()
    response.headers['Content-Description'] = 'File Transfer'
    response.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
    response.headers['Content-Length'] = _size
    response.headers['X-Accel-Redirect'] = _uri

    return response
```